# checking and setting url variable according to checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I have a mobile site and I need to give users with the option of a bright and dark interface. For that I established a checkbox, styled like an iPhone IOS7 switch. Is working as expected, but now I want to pass the status of the checkbox between pages.

I'm also using bootstrap as mobile framework.

I've searched all around and so far this is my code, can you help me figure out why is not working?

I need to set the `#indlink` link according to the status of `iface-toggle` switch. And set the `href` to `ind.html?iface=light` or `ind.html?dark`.

The console log replies with the status of the switch correctly, but for some reason, is not changing the `href` address.

I also need to set the switch on the receiving page, to the url value. I already know how to parse the url variables, and I plan to use`$('indlink').prop('checked', true)`. I haven't tested this, though, but if you can also help me with the code, it would be a blast.

**Code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  if ($("#iface-toggle").prop("checked")) {
    $("#indlink").attr("href", "ind.html?iface=light");
    console.log("checkbox is checked");
  } else {
    $("#indlink").attr("href", "ind.html?iface=dark");
    console.log("checkbox is not checked");
  }

  $("#iface-toggle").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $('body').css({
        "background-color": "white",
        "color": "black"
      });
      $('input select textarea').css({
        "color": "white"
      });
      $("#indlink").attr("href", "ind.html?iface=light");
    } else {
      $('body').css({
        "background-color": "#282c32",
        "color": "white"
      });
      $('input select textarea').css({
        "color": "black"
      });
      $("#indlink").attr("href", "ind.html?iface=dark");
    }
  })


});
```

```html
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a id="indlink" href="ind.html">Indicators</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="switch">
        <input id="iface-toggle" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round" type="checkbox">
        <label for="iface-toggle" class="label-for-check"></label>
      </div>Interface Color</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

UPDATE!!!

For documentation purposes, this is the final Javascript:

```
if(localStorage.dark == 'true') {
    $('body').css({"background-color": "#282c32", "color": "white"});
    $('input select textarea').css({"color": "black"});
    document.getElementById('iface-toggle').checked = false
} else {
    $('body').css({"background-color": "white","color": "black"});
    $('input select textarea').css({"color": "white"});
    document.getElementById('iface-toggle').checked = true
}

$("#iface-toggle").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        $('body').css({"background-color": "white","color": "black"});
        $('input select textarea').css({"color": "white"});
        localStorage.dark = 'false';
    } else {
        $('body').css({"background-color": "#282c32","color": "white"});
        $('input select textarea').css({"color": "black"});
        localStorage.dark = 'true';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use localstorage if it's all on the same domian to save and retrieve the values

set:

```
localStorage.dark = 'true';
```

get:

```
if(localStorage.dark == 'true'){
  //Do This
}
```

Note, local storage only saves as strings so make sure to keep the quotes around true.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much. I have another question, once I move to another page, and check `localStorage.dark == 'false'`, the interface changes, but the switch does not. So I want to also flip the switch and change the interface. I'm using `$('iface-toggle').prop('checked', false)`, but is not working? Any ideas?

Comment: I assume you're running this: http://callmenick.com/tutorial-demos/css-toggle-switch/ 

This worked when I tried it in the console: `document.getElementById('cmn-toggle-1').checked = true;`

Comment: Yup. That is exactly what I'm using. Outstanding. Worked like a charm. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to pass argument true pages in html is using the storage api

> Use the local storage if you want the user value to be saved such that even after the user restarts his device his preference can still be collected just like matt Coady's sample

---

> Use the session storage if you want the to set his prefrence anytime he restarts his browser

set:

```
sessionStorage.dark = 'true';
```

get:

```
if(sessionStorage.dark == 'true'){
  //Do This
}
```

---

Dont forget to remove unneeded local storage `localStorage.removeItem("dark")`

Comment: Great. I'll use the localStorage, since I want to keep the user preference to remain as the user likes it. Thanks for the tip, though. I'm sure it'll come handy in other projects.